# Scrapy, python: Unable to extract data using xpath seen in firebug

Tags: python, xpath, firebug

I am fairly new to web scraping, scrapy and python. Am trying to scrape data from this [website page](http://www.bikramyogasg.com/index.php/pricing).

I want to extract email id given in the footer of the page: info@bikramyogasg.com and have tried using two xpaths to extract this in scrapy spider:

1. Relative: id("gkFooterNav")/div/p/span/a/text()
2. Absolute: /html/body/div[4]/div[1](http://www.bikramyogasg.com/index.php/pricing)/div/div/div/p/span/a/text()

I have tried these xpaths with and without the last component of 'text()'. None of these have worked and the spider returns a null list.

However, when I check these with xpath checker, I get the correct value. Unable to figure out what's going wrong here. Can anyone help please?

Thanks,
Tuhina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse the site and look at the contents you see a message from the website:

```
This e-mail address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.
```

So you need to execute the JavaScript to get access to the email address.
Alternatively you could extract the email address from the JavaScript above this text and convert it accordingly -- without even executing any JavaScript.